# Looking for stylized H-symbol

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath, math-operators

I'm wondering if LaTeX knows the following symbol (sorry for the hand-drawing, I didn't even find it online once):

[image: Stylized H]

It's kind of a stylized `H` letter that is sometimes used to denote the Hilbert Transform. I'm aware that the Hilbert Transform is usually notated differently, but I need exactly that symbol, if available.

I checked detexify and also the comprehensive LaTeX symbol list, at least the mathematical parts and found nothing.

Edit: It is different from the calligraphic `H` (`\mathcal{H}`) which looks like this here

[image: Calligraphic H]

Comment: It's the calligraphic H: `\mathcal{H}`

Comment: No, Calligraphic H has no "loops" on bottom left and top right. See edited post

Comment: The short (and not very helpful) answer is: You can create it using METAFONT. (Not that I know how to use METAFONT myself.)

Comment: Look at `mathalfa` package documentation.

Comment: That looks like the [German cursive](http://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Datei:La-ges.jpg&filetimestamp=20060501153550&) I learned. Probably not that much help though.

Comment: Have you tried [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html)? Using my clumsy mouse skills it suggested (among other symbols) `\mathscr{H}` from the `mathrsfs` package.

Comment: My on-line handwriting recognition tool thinks: `P(\ae)=0.40`, `P(\varkappa)=0.37`, `P(\mathscr{H})=0.16`

Comment: [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) gets similar results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `H` produced by the `\mathscr` macro of the [MathTime Pro 2 Professional](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html) font package -- note that it's not free of charge -- may (or may not...) be what you're looking for:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[mtpscr]{mtpro2} % http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html
\begin{document}
$\mathscr{H}$
\end{document}
```

---

Many more possibilities present themselves if you're willing and able to use LuaLaTeX and/or XeLaTeX and the `unicode-math` package, as several modern math Opentype fonts feature a math script alphabet. Here are four more possibilities; the last one (from TeX Gyre Pagella Math) may be of particular interest to you:

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[version=XITS]{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[version=Asana]{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[version=Pagella]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\setmathfont[version=Termes]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\begin{document}
\mathversion{XITS}    $\mathscr{H}$ \quad
\mathversion{Asana}   $\mathscr{H}$ \quad
\mathversion{Termes}  $\mathscr{H}$ \quad
\mathversion{Pagella} $\mathscr{H}$ \quad
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was just about to add the same thing to my answer :)
You may wish to add the TeX Gyre Pagella version as well. It's not as curly, but it falls in the same group.

Comment: @erik -- We must be mind-reading each other: I just posted an updated MWE for the Opentype math fonts that includes TeX Gyre Pagella!

Answer (score 4):

You can get something very similar to what Mico showed using `\mathscr{H}` and `mathrsfs`, which is free.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
$\mathscr{H}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Some more free available versions:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
    Script Capital H: 

    {\fontspec{arialuni.ttf}\symbol{"210B}}
    {\fontspec{code2000.ttf}\symbol{"210B}}
    {\fontspec{dejavusans.ttf}\symbol{"210B}}
    {\fontspec{freeserif.otf}\symbol{"210B}}
    {\fontspec{mathcadunimath.otf}\symbol{"210B}}
    {\fontspec{quivira.otf}\symbol{"210B}}
    {\fontspec{symbola.ttf}\symbol{"210B}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In case, you do not want to use one of the script H letters, you might want to choose one of the following which look a bit similar:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
$\ae\varkappa\aleph$
\end{document}
```

[image]