# How do I write the title?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, beamer, table-of-contents, bibliographies

[image]

How do I write the symbol in the title in latex?

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd answer provide the symbol that you are looking for, combined with a subscript `\infty`.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212050/looking-for-stylized-h-symbol, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/625553/special-symbol-of-h.